Method does not exist error
Hi All I have written this code. can you help me spot the error
public class CollectionDataTypes {
    public static void mymethod(){
        list<integer> Listofintegers = new list<integer>();
        Listofintegers.add(11);
        Listofintegers.add(12);
        Listofintegers.add(13);
        Listofintegers.add(14);
        Listofintegers.add(15);
        Listofintegers.add(16);
        Listofintegers.add(17);
        system.debug('The List of integers is--->'+Listofintegers);
    }
}

Getting issue as the method does not exist.

Please [edit] your question to include the entirety of the error message (and the stack trace), verbatim. By trying to shorten the error, you've left out the most important parts of it. Without the full error message, it's unlikely that anyone will be able to help you.

So the error is occurring in your anonymous apex. Screenshots are usually not preferred (less accessible, harder to read), but in this case it was quite helpful. It appears that your CollectionDataTypes class is still being "saved" in Salesforce. I.e. you won't be able to call CollectionDataTypes.mymethod() until that class finishes saving. You may just need to wait a while longer, or you may need to close and re-open the developer console and create that method (maybe the entire class) again.

Thanks a lot for the help  it worked !!!

At the time of the screenshot, the Developer Console's tab on top says Saving: CollectionDataTypes. This means the server hasn't compiled the code yet, so the method didn't exist from the server's perspective.

While not usually preferred, that screenshot contained some vital information.
If you look at the rightmost tab in the dev console, it says that CollectionDataTypes.apxc is still being saved.
So the class hasn't yet made it into your org, which explains why you can't use it yet and get the Method does not exist or incorrect signature error.
You may just need to wait a little longer for the CollectionDataTypes class to finish saving.
Sometimes, for reasons unknown, the dev console can get a bit stuck. In that case, you would want to close the dev console and re-open it. You should expect to need to re-create the class (or the method, or whatever changes you were trying to make) if you do this.

Indeed. Without the screenshot, everything would seem "normal."

@sfdcfox before the screenshot, in the back of my mind, I was also wondering if this was a name shadowing issue.


while you are practicing coding in Dev console of your Org, it actually takes time to load and get saved.
first let your apex class get saved, then Execute it in Ananymous window.
it will work


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
